# win_find FAILED! => {"msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'files'"}

Tags: ansible

I am trying to run win_find with variables for "paths" to find temp files (e.g. c:\users\public\appdata\local\temp) but when I pass it to debug I get the error message

```
"FAILED! => {"msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'files'"}"
```

I have tried swapping the "register" and "with_items" lines but that seems to make no difference at all.

```
- hosts: windows-02
  vars:
    dir: \AppData\Local\Temp\
  tasks:
  - name: find user directories
    win_find:
      paths: c:\users
      recurce: yes
      file_type: directory
      get_checksum: no
    register: user_dir

  - name: debug 1
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item.path + dir }}"
    loop: "{{ user_dir.files }}"

  - name: find temp files
    win_find:
      paths: "{{ item.path + dir }}"
      recurce: yes
      hidden: yes
      get_checksum: no
    register: files_to_delete
    with_items: "{{ user_dir.files }}"

  - name: debug
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ files_to_delete.files }}"

  - name: remove
    win_file:
      path: "{{ item.path }}"
      state: absent
    with_items: "{{ files_to_delete.files }}"
```

I expect to get a list of files to be deleted which will be passed to the "win_files" module.  Instead I'm getting the error message

```
"FAILED! => {"msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'files'"}"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in win_find module, it is **recurse: yes**
Please find the below code whcih worked for me

```
---
 - name: Find files 
   win_find:
    paths: "{{paths}}"
    age: "{{duration}}"
   register: log_files

 - name: Delete the files 
   win_file:
    path: "{{item.path}}"
    state: absent
   with_items: "{{log_files.files}}"
```

Also files_to_delete will not have files_to_delete.files as it is in loop. It will have files_to_delete.results

Comment: Thanks very much for catching my typo.  I fixed that.  This playbook is supposed to be a three step process.  First to find a list of user directories.  Second, to find a list of files in the users temp directories.  Third to remove the files.  The second part seems to be where I'm having the issue (I think).  It does find the temp directories because if one is missing, it bombs out.  But it doesn't look like a list of files is being returned.  I've tried a simpler solution for cleaning out C:\Windows\Temp similar to your code and it works well.  Don't know what to look at next. :-(

Comment: Have you noticed the last line in the answer. Also files_to_delete will not have files_to_delete.files as it is in loop. It will have files_to_delete.results. Have you tired this?

Comment: I caught that and changed it to "results" yesterday.  It gets past the debug task but I get the same error on the win_file task. :-(

Comment: files_to_delete doesnt have files_to_delete.files, you need to change to files_to_delete.results

Comment: I was able to sort out the issue.  I added an answer to this thread.

Answer (score 0):

So, it appears that win_find, at least in my case, does not return files when using "when_items".  I got around this by creating a list of paths and passing it into the "paths" parameter of the module.

Here is my code:

```
- hosts: "{{ host }}"
  vars:
    dir: \AppData\Local\Temp\
    temp_paths: []
    line_break: \n
  tasks:
  - name: find user directories
    win_find:
      paths: c:\users
      recurse: no
      file_type: directory
      get_checksum: no
    register: user_dir

  - name: debug 1
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item.path + dir }}"
    loop: "{{ user_dir.files }}"

  - name: set temp path
    set_fact: temp_paths="{{temp_paths + [ item.path + dir ] }}"
    when:  item.path != 'C:\\users\\Public'
    with_items: "{{ user_dir.files }}"

  - name: find temp files
    win_find:
      paths: "{{ temp_paths }}"
      recurse: True
      patterns: '*'
      hidden: False
      get_checksum: False
    register: files_to_delete
 #   ignore_errors: yes

  - name: debug
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item.path }}"
    loop: "{{ files_to_delete.files }}"

  - name: remove
    win_file:
      path: "{{ item.path }}"
      state: absent
    with_items: "{{ files_to_delete.files }}"
```